Do I benefit from RabbitMQ when I have no integrations?
I have a shop that has big purchase peaks every now and then. Server can become unresponsive at those times with even the biggest server available. The shop does not have any ERP integrations and many RabbitMQ tutorials suggest that those specifically would benefit from using RabbitMQ.
My question is, does the basic Magento 2 CE installation benefit from using RabbitMQ and does it require anything else than just the basic change in env.php settings (+ installing RabbitMQ of course)? Do I need to create an extension in order to benefit from RabbitMQ?

Do you have Varnish cache to begin with?

Does Varnish somehow affect RabbitMQ? I do know that Varnish serves static content very quickly.

No. Varnish does not affect and doesn't have any relation to RabbitMQ. My point about Varnish is purely due to your mention of performance issues ("unresponsive"). Varnish helps to cache dynamic pages, it's a priority software to utilize in comparison to RabbitMQ component.

@DanilaVershinin Understood and agreed. However I wanted to know more about RabbitMQ as I am unfamiliar with it. I wondered if it could also help those peak moments.
